# Contract continuity in the eUTxO model

Tags: transaction, eutxo

The [paper which introduces the eUTxO model](https://iohk.io/en/research/library/papers/the-extended-utxo-model/) mentions an idea called *contract continuity*:

> we need to be able to enforce that
> the same contract code is used along the entire sequence of transactions — we
> call this *contract continuity*

and that continuity is achieved by passing the entire transaction to the validator:

> Thus a validator can inspect the transaction
> that attempts to spend its output and, in particular, it can ensure that the
> contract output of that transaction uses validator code belonging to the same
> contract — often, this will be the same validator

Based on my current understanding, it's intuitive to me that if a transaction consumes outputs from a single contract, the validator of those outputs can enforce that the new outputs of the transaction use the same validator.

What I'm having trouble understanding is what happens when a single transaction consumes two UTxOs with different contracts. Suppose there are two UTxOs `a` and `b` and that UTxO `a` is validated by `scriptA` while UTxO `b` is validated by `scriptB`. If a single transaction `tx` consumes both `a` and `b`, how is contract continuity preserved?

EDIT: I realize the second item I quoted above isn't quite clear to me and another question popped into my mind, how does `validator code` relate to the notion of `contract` and `contract output`?